# How to add new elements to the config object of Keras models?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I'm in trouble with adding new elements to the config object of Keras models.

We can get the config object with the following code:
`config = model.get_config()`

But, I can not find any methods like `model.set_condig()`.
I'd like to set my own elements to it.

Anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
from keras.models import model_from_config

new_model = model_from_config(your_config)
```